# Control Statement Bad Style

Tags: c++, coding-style

Are either of them considered a bad style of programming?

Edit: The code below, just add de value of i into pseudoRandom variable, to generate a "random" number... This is just for clear my question.

```
int pseudoRandom{};
int i{44};
while(i)
{
    pseudoRandom += i;
    i--; // decrement here
}
```

Or:

```
int pseudoRandom{};
int i{44};
while(i--) // or here
{
    pseudoRandom += i;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: 1) They are potentially different, depending on how `i` is used in "do something". 2) Opinion 'code style' otherwise; this one probably has little in terms of *objective* answers. -- I recommend going for *clearest code in context*, first.

Comment: Thank you. The only purpose is to see if while(i--) is a bad style. For clear me a doubt. Sorry for my english too.

Comment: There is nothing particularly/necessarily bad about it. It's quite an idiomatic (common) form that works in *many* cases, assuming that `i` is accepted to be 'pre-decremented' inside the loop. If this makes it more/less suitable depends on this difference, as well as preference/design of the remaining loop structure.

Answer (score 1):

You initialize a variable that controls the loop, test it every iteration, and adjust it every iteration without fail. Those are indicative of a `for` loop, not a `while`.

As such, I would say that this is not idiomatic C++. The proper idiom would be:

```
for(int i = 44; i != 0; --i)
{
  pseudoRandom += i;
}
```

If you need `i` after the loop, you can move `int i = 44` out of the `for` statement. But otherwise, nothing else should change.

Comment: Alright, thank you. for for increment, decrement loops, and while for bool values, thanks again.